# How to keep adjusted picture inside middle div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made my width's and height's "max" and the wider images are perfect inside the container but the longer ones, height wise, seem to float left of the container. I am not sure why, i researched about the adjusting on this site and they told me about the "max-width" etc. Here is the code.

```
#top-bar{
                background-color: 54D954;
                width: 100%;
                height: 45px;
                margin: 0 auto;

            }
            body{
                padding:0;
                margin: 0;

            }
            h1{
                color:white;
                font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #container{
                max-width: 1000px;
                max-height: 700px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-top: 55px;

            }
            #bottom-bar{
                width: 700px;
                height: 75px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-top: 45px;

            }
            #left{
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                float:left;

            }
            #right{
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                float:right;
            }
            #img{
                max-width: 1000px;
                max-height: 700px;

            }
        </style>
        <body>

            <div id="top-bar">
            <h1>KidsWow Pictures</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="container">
                <img id="img" src="todaypics/img1.jpg"> 


            </div>

            <div id="bottom-bar">
                <img id="left" onClick ="slides(-1)" src="Pictures/trans-left.png">
                <img id="right" onClick ="slides(1)" src="Pictures/trans-right.png">


            </div>



        <script type="text/javascript">
            var numbercounter = 1
            var total = 30

            function slides(x) {
                var Images = document.getElementById("img");
                numbercounter = numbercounter + x;
                if (numbercounter>total) {
                    numbercounter = 1;
                }
                if (numbercounter<1){
                    numbercounter = total;
                }
                Images.src = "todaypics/img"+numbercounter+".jpg";
            }   




            </script>
        </body>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the images in a `<center></center>`, that is if you want them centered. Otherwise, you might want to try a table. However, your question is quite vague as to how you want them to be aligned.

Comment: That worked, thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should centralize the image inside your container.

```
        #container{
          margin-top: 55px;
          text-align: center;
        }
        #container img {
          max-width: 1000px;
        }
```

```js
var numbercounter = 1
var total = 30

function slides(x) {
  var Images = document.getElementById("img");
  numbercounter = numbercounter + x;
  if (numbercounter>total) {
    numbercounter = 1;
  }
  if (numbercounter<1){
    numbercounter = total;
  }
  Images.src = "todaypics/img"+numbercounter+".jpg";
}
```

```css
#top-bar{
                background-color: 54D954;
                width: 100%;
                height: 45px;
                margin: 0 auto;

            }
            body{
                padding:0;
                margin: 0;

            }
            h1{
                color:white;
                font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #container{
              margin-top: 55px;
              text-align: center;
            }
            #container img {
              max-width: 1000px;
            }
            #bottom-bar{
                width: 700px;
                height: 75px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-top: 45px;

            }
            #left{
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                float:left;

            }
            #right{
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                float:right;
            }
            #img{
                max-width: 1000px;
                max-height: 700px;

            }
```

```html
<body>

            <div id="top-bar">
            <h1>KidsWow Pictures</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="container">
                <img id="img" src="todaypics/img1.jpg" /> 
            </div>

            <div id="bottom-bar">
                <img id="left" onClick ="slides(-1)" src="Pictures/trans-left.png" alt="left" />
                <img id="right" onClick ="slides(1)" src="Pictures/trans-right.png" alt="right" />
            </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh i get it, Thank you very much.